# SmartGwt - Display whole content of Label

Tags: java, gwt, user-interface, smartgwt

I've got problem with displaying full content of Label in VStack.
In my VStack are few Labels one of them has content that contains a lot of text and some images, all of it is just html. It causes two little different bugs.
In firefox it cuts bottom part of that Label, but it works when FF windows is resizing, in Chrome it cuts the same part but resize window doesn't help (whole content of label is still inside).
Could anyone help me ?

```
private Label createBodyLabel(String body) {
    Label bodyLabel = new Label();
    bodyLabel.setWidth100();
    bodyLabel.setMargin(25);
    bodyLabel.setBorder("0px solid #808080");
    bodyLabel.setBackgroundColor("#FFFFFF");
    bodyLabel.setContents(body);
    return bodyLabel;
}
```

Comment: Please can you share a reproducible code. Have you applied some custom your css styles?

Comment: Is it enough? I didn't add any special css for this

Answer (score 0):

Try it again after moving the styles in CSS file instead of directly settting it in code.

CSS:

```
.myLabel{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #808080;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

JAVA:

```
private Label createBodyLabel(String body) {
    Label bodyLabel = new Label();
    bodyLabel.setStyleName("myLabel");
    bodyLabel.setContents(body);
    return bodyLabel;
}
```

---

I never suggest you to set the style in code itself but still if you are interested then tye with [Style](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Style.html) that is obtained by calling [Element#getStyle()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Element.html#getStyle%28%29).

Comment: This is strange. On FF it works perfectly(well almost, margin doesn't work from css this way), but on Chrome content of this label is displaying under next label and still not all of it ;/

Comment: Have you tried with the second option as suggested in the end?

Comment: Yes, but now I know what is going on. It's problem with image that is loaded after Canvas is created, if image didn't have set height inside html it will cut part of content. Nevertheless thx for help